# How to remove validators in angular 4 dynamic form

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have the below form group.

```
this.rForm = fb.group({
'categoryName': [null, Validators.required],
'categoryImage': [null, Validators.required],
'mainCategoryId': [null, Validators.required],
'subCategoryName': [null, Validators.required]
});
```

And "mainCategoryId" refers to a dropdownlist. When i change value in that drowpdown, according to the value, i want to keep or remove the validators of "subCategoryName". Then i use below code in ngOnInit().

```
this.rForm.get('mainCategoryId').valueChanges.subscribe(
    (mainCategoryId) => {
       if(!this.isSub){
          this.rForm.get('subCategoryName').clearValidators();
          this.rForm.get('subCategoryName').updateValueAndValidity;
       }
    }
 );
```

It comes inside the IF statement, but it is not removing the validators. Still checks for required. What am i doing wrong? I simply want to remove the validation for required.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
this.rForm.controls['subCategoryName'].clearValidators();
```

or  you can use setvalidators and set it to null

```
this.rForm.controls['subCategoryName'].setValidators(null);
```

Comment: No. It didnt make any difference. Same result

Comment: is required validation is triggered before removing the validators

Comment: if validation is triggerred it wont remove it